# Rmarkdown - Como criar um .pdf com nome diferente do .Rmd?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Criei um script em .Rmd que será reproduzido para diferentes anos. Por isso, gostaria de poder alterar o nome do .pdf gerado.

Como é: Arquivo Relatorio.Rmd gera Relatorio.pdf

Como eu gostaria: Arquivo Relatorio.Rmd gera Relatorio_2017.pdf

```
---
title: "Titulo"
subtitle: "Subtitulo - 2017"
author: "Eu"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"

output:
  pdf_document: 
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    latex_engine: xelatex

header-includes:
  - \usepackage[portuges]{babel}
  - \usepackage{setspace}  \singlespacing
indent: false #
mainfont: Arial
monofont: Arial
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: "left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"

abstract: \singlespacing  Resumo aqui

---
```

Comment: Tente rodar o documento com `rmarkdown::render()` ou `knitr::knit()` aí você pode passar o nome.

Comment: Obrigado ! Vou tentar !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `render` para isso. Lembrando que essa função não pode ficar dentro do arquivo `.rmd`, ela tem que estar dentro de um arquivo `.R`.

Código

```
render(input = "nomeDoSeuArquivo.Rmd",
       output_file = "nomeDesejado.pdf",
       output_format = pdf_document,
       knit_root_dir = getwd(),
       encoding = "UTF-8",
       quiet = TRUE)
```

Outra opção é utilizar a função `file.rename`.

Código:

```
file.rename(from = "nomeDoSeuArquivo.pdf",
            to = paste0(nomeDesejado - ", "ano", ".pdf"))
```

Comment: Valeu! Muito obrigado!